# Overriding Liferay JSP using a hook

Tags: jsp, hook, liferay, liferay-6

I'm trying to override a JSP in Liferay 6.1, namely html/portlet/enterprise_admin/settings/authentication.jsp.

I have

- created a hook (using Eclipse, if that matters)
- added `<custom-jsp-dir>/WEB-INF/jsps</custom-jsp-dir>` to liferay-hook.xml
- created the abovementioned directory structure
- copied authentication.jsp there and modified it
- deployed the hook
- (restarted the server, you never know...)

Deployment seems to work fine. On the server I now have authentication.jsp and authentication.portal.jsp and the former contains my changes.

However, I don't see any changes when I go Portal Settings -> Authentication

What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess the path is incorrect. The authentication.jsp's correct path is

> /portal-web/docroot/html/portlet/portal_settings/authentication.jsp

I checked the source, and in Liferay 6.1, there is no portlet called enterprise admin.

So please change the folder structure.

Comment: That was my mistake. And a silly one it was. I copied the structure from 6.0. Thank you!